# Creating a Cron job for URL

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, cpanel, cron-task

I have a have a website that automatically pulls feeds and the operations works fine if I input a URL on my browser but I cannot open the URL on my browser every time. So I created a cron job on my cPanel for the link to be visited every 5 min, but it is not working. I have tried different codes, still noway.

Firstly this.
`*/5 * * * *    curl --request GET 'https://example.com/?pull-feeds=7b2e9c8d534d6c38ca98c726899b6153'`

This was the result of the first
[image]

Secondly: `* * * * *    wget -O - https://example.com/?pull-feeds=7b2e9c8d534d6c38ca98c726899b6153`

Thirdly: `* * * * * wget -qO /dev/null https://example.com/?pull-feeds=7b2e9c8d534d6c38ca98c726899b6153`

And still none of them is working, except i manually put `https://example.com/?pull-feeds=7b2e9c8d534d6c38ca98c726899b6153` on my browser.

Comment: Please, do not post images of errors. You can copy the text and paste it to make it reusable. [There's an article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) with more explanation of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use lynx text browser (if your server does not have lynx, install it).

then use

```
 */5 * * * * /usr/bin/lynx https://example.com/?pull-feeds=7b2e9c8d534d6c38ca98c726899b6153 -dump
```

Comment: am hosting the website on hostinger and i have contacted them, they say they cant install lynx on their server

Comment: Did you try curl -X or (curl -i) ?

Comment: I have a suggestion - find an old windows PC, turn it on, install the lynx (https://invisible-island.net/lynx/) and then set a scheduler to run the lynx to visit the link you need every 5 minutes (since hostinger does not allow you to install lynx)